# how to display the result in same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

it is my code.
html

```
<html>
<head></head>
</body>
<form id="myform" action="formdata.php" method="post">
    username:<input type="text" name="username" id="name"><br>
    password:<input type="password" name="password" id="pass"><br>
    firstname:<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
    lastname:<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="register">
</form>
<div id="status_text"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var username = $('#name').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
    var firstname = $('#fname').val();
    var lastnamee = $('#lname').val();
    var postData = '&username='+username+'&password='+password+'&firstname='+firstname+'&lastname='+lastname;
    var status_text = $('#status_text');
    //alert(postData);
    //var mydata = {'username':name,'password':pass,'firstname':fname,'lastname':lname};
/*$.post($('#myform').attr('action'),
    $('#myform:input').serializeArray(),
    function(info){
        $('status_text').html(info)
    });*/
$.ajax({
    url:"action",
    type:"post",
    success:function(info)
    {
        status_text.html(info);
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it is my php code for database

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO karthik.person(name,password,firstname,lastname)VALUES('$name','$password','$firstname','$lastname')";
if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo("record added success");
}else{
    echo("failed".$conn->error);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

when ever i run this code it goes to next page and display the result like "record added successfully" instead of that i want the code to display the result in the same page. i almost tried all ways but i can't get my expected result.

Comment: url:"action" is 'formdata.php' @PhiterFernandes

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the browser not to submit the form:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default behaviour for the submit-action
    //... the rest of your code
```

When you get this working, you should start fixing stuff from [@jeroen's list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943087/2453432).

Comment: That's just the start :-)

Comment: @jeroen - He does say that he do get the correct result, but just on another page so I'm guessing the code in the question has been modified for SO. But yes, there are multiple issues with his code. I'm just answering the actual question. :)

Comment: @jeroen - I 100% agree.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried your solution and it doesn't works :(

Comment: Could you elaborate "doesn't work"? Does the same thing happen or is there something else happening, like an error message?

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems here:

- You are not preventing the default submit event and that causes the form to submit "normally" as well.
- You are not sending any data with your ajax request so you will never have any `$_POST` variables on the server-side.
- You have an sql injection problem. You should use a prepared statement and bind the values.
- You are not sending your ajax request to the correct url.
- You are using a plain-text password. You should always salt and hash passwords.